# Force to load all widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Slivers does not init all of the widget when those widgets are not show on the screen, can I force them to init even they are not yet shown on the screen?  thankyou

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            silverAppbar("Production Performance"),
            SliverFixedExtentList(
              itemExtent: 65.0,
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  MachineTimeCard(
                      subject: '00:00-01:00',
                      type: widget.machinetime != null
                          ? widget.machinetime.job00
                          : "",
                      parentAction: _updateJobType00),
                  MachineTimeCard(
                      subject: '01:00-02:00',
                      type: widget.machinetime != null
                          ? widget.machinetime.job01
                          : "",
                      parentAction: _updateJobType01),
                  MachineTimeCard(
                      subject: '02:00-03:00',
                      type: widget.machinetime != null
                          ? widget.machinetime.job02
                          : "",  
'''and there are many more MachineTimeCard for time around the clock'''
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to ask. What does `Slivers does not init` mean?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

sorry i did not ask my question clear (not enough coffee), after all I have put all 24 MachineTimeCard() into a Column(), and the system would initialize all of 24 MachineTimeCard() when it load the screen even some of the MachineTimeCard() is out of the screen.  I think it might be not a very good practice for sliver but I can't find a better way to make it work.  thankyou for everyone helped.

Comment: You could add the same to your question. You have just posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just make them variable, you could initialize them in the initState function.
Like this :

```
MachineTimeCard myMachineTimeCard;

@override
void initState() {
   myMachineTimeCard = MachineTimeCard();
   super.initState();
}
```

And then, just add it in your code :

```
delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
   myMachineTimeCard,
]),
```